# Is there any way of viewing revision history on files in Wordpress?

Tags: templates

I have done some tiny changes to my **style.css** file and my **header.php** file.

For want of a better word I have destroyed my website, and i am losing my mind trying to figure out what I did wrong, ie  is there a comma or semicolon out of place.

Is there any way of getting revision history on template files?

Comment: You should seriously think to start using a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). [**Git**](http://git-scm.com/) is the most used nowadays and easily pair with the popular [github](https://github.com/). To get started there is an [ebook downloadable for free](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). If you start to use a version control system you'll ask yourself how you did without it.

Comment: Simple answer: no. I know it's neither here nor there now, but moral of the story: Do not use the WordPress file editor. And backup.

Answer (score 2):

No. The only revision system wordpress has is for the post content and maybe title.

Comments suggested using revision systems when you make code level changes at your site, but even before that you should use a backup tool and backup the site before doing any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for when I did the same thing as you. Simply take the modified stylesheet that you messed up on, and then take the original theme stylesheet, and run it through this difference checking website:

https://www.diffchecker.com/

It will highlight any differences between the two files. It saved me, hopefully people who are having the same problem with see this answer and it can save you too!